# How to set up a spring based java library?

Tags: spring, autowired

I am trying to create a java library that uses spring. But I am not able to find any resources that shows you how to set up component scan and load all beans when you do not have a main entry point into the application.

Answer (score 1):

A common approach used by spring is to define a `@EnableXXXX` and let the client of your library to enable it by annotating it on their configuration class. Something like :

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Import(FooLibarayConfiguration.class)
@Documented
public @interface EnableFooLibaray{

}
```

```java
@ComponentScan("xxxxx")
@Configuration
public class FooLibarayConfiguration{

}
```

And client enables your library by :

```java
@EnableFooLibaray
@Configuration
public class Application{

}
```

The `@Import` actually supports a more dynamic way to include the bean settings for your library. You can refer to many existing `@EnableXXX` provided by spring such as `@EnableAsync` ,  `@EnableWebSecurity` , `@EnableTransactionManagement` , `@EnableCaching` etc. for many examples.